# execjs error on launching Rails application expecting kEND

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I created a new Rails project by using the `rails new RubyTest` command,  but it fails with the following error when I run it with `rails s`.

```
$ rails s
c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs.rb:2:in `require': c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems
/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
      name:        "Node.js (V8)",
           ^
c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting k
END
c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting k
END
c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:24: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting k
END
c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:26: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting k
END
c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '
)'
      name:        "JavaScriptCore",
           ^
c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting k
END
c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:30: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting k
END
c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:32: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting k
END
c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:35: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '
)'
      name:        "SpiderMonkey",
           ^
c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:35: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting k
END
c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:36: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting k
END
c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting k
END
c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:42: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '
)'
      name:        "JScript",
           ^
c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:42: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting k
END
c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:43: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting k
END
c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:44: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting k
END
c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:46: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting k
END
        from c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-2.2.2/lib/execjs.rb:2
        from c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.3.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
        from c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.3.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1
        from c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.3.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
        from c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.3.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1
        from c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
        from c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1
        from c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
        from c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
        from C:/Dev/apptana_wksp/RubyTest/config/application.rb:7
        from c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
        from c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:53
        from c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from c:/apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:50
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6
```

No class has been added yet, it's just blank.

For now everything is default, no object is been added.

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.14.  This seems like an environment-specific issue. Do I have to install any specific gem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on how to properly format a question. It's important that your document be easily readable, as those who will help you are working in their free time. If you waste it they'll either move on without trying to help, or they'll miss important information.

Answer (score 0):

Error logs highlight a new feature of Ruby 1.9 - alternate syntax for symbols as hash keys.

There are some lines like this one, where Ruby chokes on a colon:

```
name: "JavaScriptCore",
```

What was formerly to be written as:

```
{ :symbol => value }
```

Can be written in 1.9+ as:

```
{ symbol: value }
```

It looks much better (for me at least, since it's shorter but expresses the same meaning), so this syntax is now widely used.

But Rubies prior to 1.9 don't support this syntax. If you don't have any specific reason to use such outdated tools, consider upgrading. Otherwise, look through dependencies and lock versions where needed. `execjs` should be locked around 1.4.0 [as commits suggest](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs/commits/master?page=2), shortly afterwards a requirement on Ruby 1.9.2 was introduced.

Comment: Thanks D-side. Yes after locking execjs to 1.40, this problem got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the coffeescript files that were automatically generated. go to your app assets javascript and delete all the coffee script folders and try it out. 
It worked for me perfectly on windows 10. 
If it didn't please say what happened because i struggled with this for a whole day and got a punch of solutions for different types of problems leading to the same error.